# python - fastest time to populate unique values row-wise for 8 million rows dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named `report1`; with the size  of  14 colums  X  8 million rows. What I would like to do is to get unique values of each row from column 3 through to column 8 and populate the result of each row onto a new dataframe named `df`.

`report1` (source data) looks like below:

Ticket Number      Col0   Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4  Col5   Col6   Col7   Col8

100                       21      30     32       3        4       6        1        5        0

101                        4         9    25        3       4       6        1        5        4

102                       45       33    11       3        4       6        1        5        3

…  …  …  …  …  …  …  …  …  …

8000000                12        5     28       3       4        6        1       5       11

`df` (new dataframe)should be like this:

Ticket Number     Col0    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6   Col7  Col8

100                       21      30     32        3        4       6        1        5        0

101                        4         9     25        3       4       6         1        5      nan

102                      45       33      11       3        4       6         1       5       nan

…  …  …  …  …  …  …  …  …  …

8000000              12        5       28        3       4       6          1       5      11

So far I have been able to get what I wanted from the simple script below but it just takes too long to run it through even if  I have tried get it run under pythonanywhere platform.

Anyone knows how to get this done in the shortest possible time?

The script is as follows:

```
result = []
for i in range(0,7999999):
    g = pd.unique(report1.iloc[i,7:13].values.ravel())

    arr_list = g.tolist()
    result.append(arr_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `numpy`:

```
data = report1.iloc[:,4:10].values
sort_idx = np.argsort(data,axis=1)
row_offset = data.shape[1]*np.arange(data.shape[0])[:,None]
sort_lin_idx = sort_idx[:,1::] + row_offset
dup_lin_idx = sort_lin_idx[np.diff(np.sort(data,axis=1),axis=1)==0]
a = data.ravel().astype(float)
a[dup_lin_idx] = np.nan
data = a.reshape(len(data), -1)
print (pd.DataFrame(data))

     0    1    2    3    4     5
0  3.0  4.0  6.0  1.0  5.0   0.0
1  3.0  4.0  6.0  1.0  5.0   NaN
2  3.0  4.0  6.0  1.0  5.0   NaN
3  3.0  4.0  6.0  1.0  5.0  11.0
```

**Timings**:

```
In [117]: %timeit (orig(report1))
1 loop, best of 3: 7.48 s per loop

In [118]: %timeit (jez1(report1))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.82 s per loop

In [119]: %timeit (jez2(report1))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.57 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
#[40000 rows x 6 columns]
report1 = pd.concat([report1]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

def orig(df):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        g = pd.unique(report1.iloc[i,4:10].values.ravel())
        arr_list = g.tolist()
        result.append(arr_list)
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    return (df)

def jez1(df):
    df = report1.iloc[:,4:10]
    return (df.where(~df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1), np.nan))

def jez2(report1):
    data = report1.iloc[:,4:10].values
    sort_idx = np.argsort(data,axis=1)
    row_offset = data.shape[1]*np.arange(data.shape[0])[:,None]
    sort_lin_idx = sort_idx[:,1::] + row_offset
    dup_lin_idx = sort_lin_idx[np.diff(np.sort(data,axis=1),axis=1)==0]
    a = data.ravel().astype(float)
    a[dup_lin_idx] = np.nan
    data = a.reshape(len(data), -1)
    return (pd.DataFrame(data))

print (orig(report1))    
print (jez1(report1))
print (jez2(report1))
```