# Faster Way of Getting Distinct Rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a PySpark dataframe with ~10M rows. Is there a a faster way of getting distinct rows compared to `df.distinct()`? Maybe use `df.groupBy()`?

Comment: Try to reduce the size of the input by selecting only relevant columns and filtering out irrelevant rows.

It would help if we knew more about the input schema and what you want to get out of the data

Comment: @gatear: Most of the ~10M rows are identical and the rest are distinct. In that case, would you suggest adding another column that gives the hash of the concatenation of the existing columns?

Comment: also how is `df.distinct()` failing your expectations\requirements right now ?

Comment: @gatear: it's taking too long

Comment: any use?
https://coiled.io/blog/speed-up-pandas-query-10x-with-dask/

Comment: @JonTout: No. This is for PySpark dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

if you try select the columns of interest before you do the operation then wil be faster (smaller dataset).

something like

```
python
columns_to_select = ["col1", "col2"]
df.select(columns_to_select).distinct()
```

Comment: what if you already did that?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `np.unqiue(df.coloum_name.values)`, which is a faster operation compared to `df.unique()`

Check out the following link for comparative performance measures:

[python - fastest time to populate unique values row-wise for 8 million rows dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415926/python-fastest-time-to-populate-unique-values-row-wise-for-8-million-rows-data)